# How can simpify and clear the expression to get the cell value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My target dataframe is something as below:

```
df
                    SimFinId Currency  Fiscal Year  ... Net Extraordinary Gains (Losses)  Net Income Net Income (Common)
Ticker Report Date                                  ...                                                                 
A      2018-10-31      45846      USD         2018  ...                              NaN   316000000           316000000
       2019-10-31      45846      USD         2019  ...                              NaN  1071000000          1071000000
       2020-10-31      45846      USD         2020  ...                              NaN   719000000           719000000
       2021-10-31      45846      USD         2021  ...                              NaN  1210000000          1210000000
       2022-10-31      45846      USD         2022  ...                              NaN  1254000000          1254000000
...                      ...      ...          ...  ...                              ...         ...                 ...
ZYXI   2018-12-31     171401      USD         2018  ...                              NaN     9552000             9552000
       2019-12-31     171401      USD         2019  ...                              NaN     9492000             9492000
       2020-12-31     171401      USD         2020  ...                              NaN     9074000             9074000
       2021-12-31     171401      USD         2021  ...                              NaN    17103000            17103000
       2022-12-31     171401      USD         2022  ...                              NaN    17048000            17048000
```

I want to get the cell(Net Income (Common))'s value whose ticker name is `A` and `Fiscal Year` is 2019.

```
df[df['Fiscal Year'] == 2019].loc['A','Net Income (Common)'].values[0]
1071000000
```

How can simpify and clear the expression to get the cell value?

Comment: Do you mean "simplify and clarify"? I'm not sure how you would "clear" an expression.

Comment: 1. Create an example that has completeness without ellipses (...). The example is necessary for reproducibility, and elliptical expressions can make it difficult to reproduce. 

 2. Removing unnecessary columns and creating a minimal example also makes it easier to get an answer. 

 3. Also, if you have a multi-index, it is better to provide an example
    with code rather than a text table.

Comment: @PandaKim Agree. For more details, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: I think this is a bit clearer: `f.query('Ticker=="A" and `Fiscal Year`==2019')['Net Income (Common)'].iloc[0]`

Comment: ``Fiscal Year`` in the back ticks.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
df.xs('A', level=0).loc[lambda x: x['Fiscal Year'].eq(2019), 'Net Income (Common)'].values[0]
```

out:

```
1071000000
```

another approach

```
cond1 = df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'A'
cond2 = df['Fiscal Year'].eq(2019)
df.loc[cond1 & cond2,  'Net Income (Common)'].values[0]
```

same result

Comment: df.query('Ticker=="A" and Fiscal Year==2019')['Net Income (Common)'].iloc[0]

Comment: I like most, although lengthy, it is logically coherent.

Answer (score 0):

If `Fiscal Year` is computed from `Report Date` (the year part), maybe you can simply do:

```
>>> df.loc[('A', '2019'), 'Net Income (Common)'].squeeze()
1071000000.0
```

Assume `Fiscal Year` is a `DatetimeIndex`.